# pycharm shortkeys are overriden by the OS shortkeys in mac

Tags: macos, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using MAC.

My short keys in PyCharm suddenly stopped working and are overriden by the MacOS shortkeys.

How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You can head over to Preferences > Keymap and then set them to the shortkeys that you are used to having.

[image: Keymap]

Comment: the problem is not that I have fault shortkeys - the problem is that doesn't work at all